# Send stdout or stderr to a new thread

Tags: c, multithreading

For performance issue I want the logging send to a new thread.

While the main program can work, the new thread can write the error or other messages to a file without effect to the main program. How could I send all stdout to the new thread?

Work to be done:

- create a new thread, ok
- open a file, ok
- create a pipe inside the thread, ok
- send stdout to the new thread, with freopen or dup?

Every time the buffer gets full, or every 5 seconds the log file gets new data.

Because it is an [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) program, I can't fork the whole program. It has to be a Posix thread.

Comment: Whatever inter-thread communication mechanism you choose, unless your application pegs CPU usage to near 100% (I would hope that isn't the case) then there's no reason to explicitly limit when the log data is written to the file (e.g buffer is full/every 5 seconds). Just run the logging thread at a lower priority than the more important threads and the logging thread continually sits there reading data which is logged as soon as its read. Let the OS decide when the log data is processed by using the unused CPU cycles to do it.

Comment: That is what I want. But how could I send new log entry's to the thread? Now I work with a linked list, you see my code in this post. But it is not stable as I want!

Comment: My favorite inter-thread mechanism is the VxWorks MessageQueue. Whatever OS I am working in, I simply create an equivalent thread-safe message queue class and use that. I believe POSIX has a message queue class of its own, but from what I remember it might be a bit heavyweight, but its been many years so I'm not sure.

Comment: VxWorks is a complete system for real time use. In detail, what do you talk about. Can you please give me a link about your subject? I use c for programming, so no class or object oriented system are availeble.

Comment: Look up vxworks msgQLib. It shows a straight functional message queue lib API. You can also find examples of usage. Why wouldn't the POSIX message queue class suit your needs?

Answer (score 5):

create an internal producer/consumer

your log call will produce a message that will be consumed by the other thread and written out to the log file

you will need to change the log call to push to the queue instead of writing to stdout but if you used a macro from the start that shouldn't be an issue ;)

edit what I mean by using a macro for logging is

```
#define LOG(s,...) printf(s,_VA_ARGS_)
```

this would then change to

```
#define LOG(s,...) do{char[] buff = new char[512]; \
          snprintf(buff,512,s,_VA_ARGS_); \
          pushToLogger(buff);}while(0)
```

`pushToLogger(char*)` is the function that does the pushing (and becomes responsible for `free`ing `buff`)

Comment: Your answer just cements one thing for sure: I will truly never understand what C/C++ macros are for... Good answer though +1 :)

Comment: with todays compilers/optimizers a header function (the inlineable kind) will be sufficient for speed and single point of change

Comment: could you make a example. I don't work with macro in c. For me as beginner I don't understand.

Comment: Ok, that make more sense. Your example is for c++, my project is written in c. In c I don't have the "new char" thing. If I understand it right, you get the messages in buff and send it with pushToLogger to what? The while loop need all CPU Power!

Comment: @Thor eh you can replace `new char[512]` with `alloc(512)`, and it pushes to a queue that gets polled by another thread

Comment: I never heard anything about alloc. I now malloc, find calloc on the web. But nothing about alloc! I understand that you push the buffer with the function to the thread. But in c without object oriented compiler. I can't call a function in a running thread. In my understanding a thread is started with a function, the thread ended after exit of the function.

Answer (score 0):

That work as expected, but is a lot of work. What are you thinking about that?
These are the structs for my list.

```
typedef struct logger {
    struct timeval *time1;
    char message[255];
    struct logger *next;
} Logger;

typedef struct queue {
    struct logger *front;
    struct logger *rear;
} Queue;
```

Inside the queue is the linked list. With folowing function, the linked list is filled with messages.

```
void addLogStruct(char* dummyMessage) {
    Logger *tmpLogger = malloc(sizeof(Logger));
    if (queue1.front == NULL ) {
        // first round initialice
        strncpy(logger1.message,
                "*** Laufzeitsystem ***",
                sizeof(logger1.message));
        static struct timeval tmpTime;
        gettimeofday(&tmpTime, NULL );
        logger1.time1 = &tmpTime;
        logger1.next = NULL;
        runLogger = &logger1;
        queue1.front = &logger1;
        queue1.rear = &logger1;
    } else {
        strncpy(tmpLogger->message, dummyMessage, sizeof(tmpLogger->message));
        static struct timeval tmpTime;
        gettimeofday(&tmpTime, NULL );
        tmpLogger->time1 = &tmpTime;
        tmpLogger->next = NULL;
        runLogger->next = tmpLogger;
        queue1.rear = tmpLogger;
        runLogger = runLogger->next;
    }
}
```

In the main function I started a detached Posix Thread. The following method run every 0.05 seconds to check the list, if a new message is there. If there is one, it will be written to disk.

```
int messageQueueThread(void *dummy) {
    Queue *tmpQueue = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    tmpQueue = (Queue*) dummy;
    Logger *runLog = malloc(sizeof(Logger));
    int must_stop = 0;
    do {
        if (tmpQueue->front != runLog) {
            // Create String for transfer to function
            char tmpString[255];
            char *tmpString2 = timeval2String(tmpQueue->front->time1);
            sprintf(tmpString, "%s %s.\n", tmpString2,
                    tmpQueue->front->message);
            // write message to disk
            writeMessageFile(tmpString);

            // another one
            runLog = tmpQueue->front;

            // reorder logger struct
            if (tmpQueue->front->next != NULL ) {
                tmpQueue->front = tmpQueue->front->next;
            }
            // delete old log message?
        } else {
            // reorder logger struct
            if (tmpQueue->front->next != NULL ) {
                tmpQueue->front = tmpQueue->front->next;
            }
        }
    } while (!busyWait(must_stop));
    return 0;
}
```

It's not perfect. But it work more or less. I want it simpler, but can't do it.